# docker-compose up command did not work well

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

working with Laravel 9 and I have installed docker toolkit as well and I am running windows 7 as well. when I run `docker-compose up` command it is generating following error message in my cmd

> Version in ".\docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
> For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

my docker-compose.yml file is like this

```yaml
version: "2.2"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.8.3
    # Uncomment below when on Mac M1
    platform: linux/arm64/v8
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `version: "2.2"` with `version: "3.9"` (of course you have to have Docker and Docker Compose up to date)... use a new version...

Here you can see what `docker` version you will need for a specific docker compose `version` file: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/